# How to simplify the polynomial $T=(a+t_1)+(a+t_1)(a+t_2)+\cdots\prod_{i=1}^n(a+t_i)-(a+a^2+\cdots a^n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, symbolic-computation

Is it possible to simplify the following polynomial?
$$T=(a+t_1)+(a+t_1)(a+t_2)+\cdots\prod_{i=1}^n(a+t_i)-(a+a^2+\cdots a^n)$$

What I think:
We can first consider a special case when $t_1=t_2=\cdots=t$, then it comes to $T=(a+t)+(a+t)^2+\cdots(a+t)^n-(a+a^2+\cdots a^n)$, but it seems also cannot be reduced.

Comment: For the case $t_1=t_2=\cdots = t$, you have two geometric series, so you can simplify by using the standard formula for the sum of  a geometric series.

Comment: note that subtracting the powers of $\alpha$ leaves only sum of products of $\alpha$ and $t_k$